# Power 5V and 3.3V components from li-ion battery

Tags: batteries, voltage-regulator, dc-dc-converter, lithium-ion, low-power

I want to make a portable device that runs of a rechargeable li-ion (4.2-2.7V) batteries. I have components that run on 3.3V (ATmega328P ,GPS) and some LEDs (5V.)
There are multiple ways I can think of to power this:

1. Use a step down from the battery for 3.3V and a step up from the battery for the 5V.
2. Use a step down from the battery for 3.3V and a step up from the 3.3V to the 5V
3. Use a step up from the battery to the 5V and a step down from the 5V to the 3.3V

Are there any other smart ways to achieve this? I'm looking for power efficiency and simplicity.

I think maybe there are more battery to 5V circuits out there that offer the ability to charge the li-ion easily. I think a voltage divider from 5V to 3.3V is to inefficient. Is there an IC that maybe allows for both?

Comment: Do you have to use 5V LEDs, and why?

Comment: Case 3 should probably read: _Use a step up from the **battery for 5V** and a step down from the 5V to the 3.3V_

Comment: @Justme yes, those are neopixels (ws2812), I need 12 of them on a single pin.

Comment: I would use a boost converter to 5V and then a cheap linear regulator down from 5V to 3.3V for the MCU.

Comment: Something as this 5 V - 3.3 V - USB charger ... https://www.amazon.fr/diymore-Blindage-Batterie-Raspberry-Arduino/dp/B07S3H1V77?th=1